# Powershell Check Windows OS Version on Remote workstation

Tags: powershell

I am looking to find out on a remote workstation it's version of windows. 
I need to pull the information from $OSCheck then check if it matches a version of Windows.

```
$computer = read-host "Computer Name "
$UserName = Read-Host "Enter User Name "
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Your Password "
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName , $Password
#Check Workstation#
$OSCheck = (Get-WmiObject -comp $computer -Credential $Credential -class Win32_OperatingSystem ).Caption    
$OSCheck
Write-Host ""
#Write-Host "OS Version is - " $OSCheck
Write-Host ""

If ($OSCheck  -match "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" )
{
    Write-Host "OSCheck is Microsoft Windows 7 Professional"
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "Not Windows 7"
}
```

Comment: other than the typo "Mircosoft" whats not working?

Comment: It keeps coming back saying Not Windows 7, I fixed the typo. :)

Comment: Your not going to post your answer?

Comment: Does `Get-WmiObject` return anything at all?

Comment: Yeah was going to post the answer, I had to wait 10hours before I could, as I don't have a high enough rep.

Comment: Get-WmiObject returns "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" now, just had to figure out the correct way to pull the information I needed.

Comment: @User79 I have no idea what your problem is here, making both the question and answers far less useful. Could you clarify it, so that future readers can know whether they have the same issue or not?

Comment: No issue now, all been updated and working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the script, working now
Changed the following -

```
$OSCheck = (Get-WmiObject -comp $computer -Credential $Credential -class Win32_OperatingSystem ).Caption
```

so it passes the variable I want to check against in to the variable. Previous line was too complicated. This is a simpler way to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

in your script, you are using $comp for the computer read-host, but for your wmi query, you're using $computer